# Azure DevOps private nuget repo Unauthorized when building with docker

Tags: docker, .net-core, azure-devops, nuget

I am trying to create a docker image for my project that has a private Azure DevOps nuget repo. I am able to connect to the repo in visual studio with my credentials but when I try to build a docker image I get an error.

> Unable to load the service index for source
>   https://{my_url}/nuget/v3/index.json Response status code does not
>   indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized)

I copied my `Nuget.config file` to the root of my project

nuget.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <disabledPackageSources>
    <add key="Microsoft and .NET" value="true" />
  </disabledPackageSources>
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
  </activePackageSource>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="libraries" value="https://{my_url}/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <libraries>
      <add key="Username" value="{my_username}" />
      <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="{my_pass}" />
    </libraries>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

and this is my `dockerfile`

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0.0-preview8-nanoserver-1903 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0.100-preview8-nanoserver-1903 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY NuGet.config "MyProject/"
COPY ["MyProject/MyProject.csproj", "MyProject/"]
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore "MyProject/MyProject.csproj"
WORKDIR "/src/MyProject"
RUN dotnet build "MyProject.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyProject.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyProject.dll"]
```

I am not sure what else to do for it to be able to connect to my repo

Answer (score 4):

I stumbled across [this post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/530691/response-status-code-does-not-indicate-success-401.html).
(ref: solution @ the bottom)

Basically, change the PAT Organization to "All accessible organizations" AND scroll through the permission\security sections and set the following:

- Build (Artifacts, definitions, requests, queue a build, and updated build properties): **Read**
- Connected server (Access endpoints): **Connected server**
- Packaging (Create, read, update, and delete feeds and packages): **Read**

(Not sure if all of these are required.)

Docker File:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-stretch-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-stretch AS build
WORKDIR /src

# The Personal Access Token arg
ARG PAT

# Set environment variables
ENV NUGET_CREDENTIALPROVIDER_SESSIONTOKENCACHE_ENABLED true
ENV VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS '{"endpointCredentials":[{"endpoint":"https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/ORG/_packaging/FEEDNAME/nuget/v3/index.json","username":"USERNAME","password":"'${PAT}'"}]}'

# Get and install the Artifact Credential provider
RUN wget -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/artifacts-credprovider/master/helpers/installcredprovider.sh  | bash

COPY ["PROJECTNAME.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore -s "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/ ORG /_packaging/ FEEDNAME /nuget/v3/index.json" -s "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json"

COPY . ./
WORKDIR /src
RUN dotnet build " PROJECTNAME.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish --no-restore " PROJECTNAME.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", " PROJECTNAME.dll"]
```

docker command:

```
docker build -t BUILDNAME:local . --build-arg PAT=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Previously we were using a nuget.config file with credentials\PAT and this was working. I have no idea what changed to cause it to stop. If anyone had an idea pls post.

Comment: The PAT settings information above is correct. I put the PAT token into the nuget.config file as the cleartextpassword and things worked fine from there. Seems that they have fixed the issue with the PAT in the nuget.config file, fyi.

Answer (score 3):

you need to force `dotnet restore` to use your config file:

```
RUN dotnet restore "MyProject/MyProject.csproj" --configfile Nuget.Config
```

alternatively you can do something like this in your dockerfile:

```
# Add Environment Variables references for access private Azure Artifacts Repository
# Use --build-arg <ARG> to pass this in.
ARG TOKENPASS
ARG TOKENUSER
ARG NUGET_ENDPOINT

# Fetch Azure Artifacts "Magic" credentials providers
RUN wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/artifacts-credprovider/master/helpers/installcredprovider.sh | bash

# Needs to be enabled to fetch the private repository credentials for NuGet restore.
ENV NUGET_CREDENTIALPROVIDER_SESSIONTOKENCACHE_ENABLED true
ENV VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS="{\"endpointCredentials\": [{\"endpoint\":\"$NUGET_ENDPOINT\", \"username\":\"$TOKENUSER\", \"password\":\"$TOKENPASS\"}]}"

# Workaround of some kind to help Azure Artifact Private repository image collection.
ENV DOTNET_SYSTEM_NET_HTTP_USESOCKETSHTTPHANDLER 0
```

and use docker build with `--build-arg TOKENPASS=$(TOKENPASS) --build-arg TOKENUSER=$(TOKENUSER) --build-arg NUGET_ENDPOINT=$(NUGET_ENDPOINT)`

Comment: I added that config file command to the restore and same issue, I am using the same credentials that I would put into Visual Studio when it asks me for them when I add the private nuget url to the nuget package manager. Should I be using different credentials?

Comment: you should be using credentials that work, have you seen this: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/6135?